# android stream audio by passing cookies as header

Tags: android

I have to play mp3 audio file from the Server Url. To make the audio to played I need to pass Cookie in the headers. So I used setDatasource(context, uri, headers) to play the media. It's not working for me.

It gives me the error:source returned error -1008, 10 retries left to source returned error -1008, 0 retries left.

Anyone can help me to get a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

Map headers = new HashMap();
headers.put("Cookie","CloudFront-Signature=xx; Domain=xx; Path=xx");
headers.put("Cookie","CloudFront-Policy:xx; Domain=xx; Path=xx");
headers.put("Cookie","CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=xx; Domain=xx; Path=XX");

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayerService.this, Uri.parse("URL"),headers);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

**Following are the links referred:**
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731603/android-mediaplayer-urls-with-cookie 
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727098/android-add-cookie-to-mediaplayer-requests
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932362/how-to-stream-authenticated-content-with-mediaplayer-on-android
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the solution by referring this link "https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/177#issuecomment-48872226". I can able to add cookies in MediaPlayer header like below. Audio Playing working in all 4.0,5.0 and 6.0 android versions without any issue. Hope this helps someone.

Important note adding \r\n at the end did the trick. Thanks for the above forum.

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

> headers.put("Cookie","CloudFront-Policy=xxx; CloudFront-Signature=xxx;
>   CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=xxx; Domain=xx; Path=xxx\r\n");

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri, headers);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
```